# Редактировать html страницу при помощи node.js файла

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть небольшое приложение на html/css/js и файл nodejs (tiktok.js) с установленным модулем tiktok-live-connector.

Дальше в файл node js поступают данные с тик тока ( сообщения из чата и их автор ) и выводятся в консоли при запуске файла через node tiktok.js

**Вопрос** как из файла tiktok.js передать данные во внутрь файла index.html желательно в конкретный блок например с id "block"

Comment: У вас есть сервер приложение nodejs, которое получает данные с какого-то ресурса, вы хотите, чтоб эти данные сразу передавались на вашу HTML страничку? - Обратите внимание на WebSocket технологию.. но боюсь, вам придется потратить на изучение процесса далеко не 1 час...

Comment: ок спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Comment: да вы были правы. только я решил использовать не вебсокеты, а SSE тк мне не нужна обратная связь клиента с сервером. спасибо вам за помощь1

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.
Как и писали мне в комментариях, нужно использовать вебсокеты или Server Side Event.

Я просто создал сервер, послал на него данные
res.write(`data: ${data.text}\n\n`);

далее создал index html файл и внутри него внутри тега скрипт написал запрос принимающий ответ с сервера на адрес локалхоста.